# Can't save date time fields to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have model with date time field after render new view and submit it all fields of model saved to database except date time field even I am using date time picker

Can any body help me to solve this problem

This is the code I am working on:

## Interview controller

```
  def new
    @interview = Interview.new(:batch_id => @batch.id)
  end

  def create
    @interview = Interview.new(interview_params)
    # Save the object
    if @interview.save
    # If save succeeds, redirect to the index action
    flash[:notice]= "تم إنشاء المقابلة بنجاح."
    redirect_to(interviews_path(:batch_id => @batch.id))
    else
    # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end
```

## Interview new view code

```
<% @page_title = "إنشاء مقابلة" %>
<div id="content-header">
  <div class='header-icon hr-icon'></div>
  <h1>المقابلات</h1>
  <div class='header-sep'>|</div>
  <div class='sub-header'>إنشاء مقابلة</div>
  <div id="inner-tab-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class='themed_bg themed-dark-hover-background'><%= link_to("<< العودة للجدول", interviews_path(:batch_id => @batch.id)) %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page-yield">
  <div class="iterviews new">
    <%= form_for(@interview, :url =>interviews_path(:batch_id => @batch.id)) do |f| %>
    <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}) %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            locale: 'ar-sa'
        });
    </script>
    <div><%= f.submit("إنشاء مقابلة", :class => 'submit_button') %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

## form code

```
<div class="label-field-pair">
  <div class="right-column">
    <label for="student_grade">رقم المقابلة<span class="necessary-field">*</span> </label>
    <div class="text-input-bg"><%= f.text_field(:code, style: "width: 240px;") %></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="label-field-pair">
  <div class="right-column">
    <label for="student_grade">تاريخ المقابلة<span class="necessary-field">*</span></label>
    <div class="text-input-bg" style="direction: ltr; margin: 0 10px 0 0;">
      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <%= f.datetime_field(:interview_date , class: "form-control", style: "width: 200px;margin: 0;") %>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%= f.hidden_field(:batch_id, value: @batch.id) %>
```

Comment: Well, it's impossible without seeing the actual code...

Comment: it seems too hard for developers to answer this kind of questions !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I could find out the solution for this problem, of course the reason was that datetimepicker doesn't understand the values in my fields so what I did is the following:

1- change the numbers in moment-with-locales.js in the 'ar-sa' section from Indian numbers to Arabic numbers.
2- set the format: option to datetimepicker to match model attribute data type format in case it is date type or datetime type

and that's solve my problem